# Mac/Windows MIDI application programming language

Tags: windows, macos, programming-languages, midi

What is the best programming language for writing MIDI-interactive musical application that would be run on MAC and on Windows?

Comment: Whatever you're familiar with that has a decent MIDI library available for it.

Comment: This question should be made wiki since there is no correct/incorrect answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written cross platform (Mac OS X and Windows) MIDI applications using C++. I used the [RtMidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) for MIDI I/O which was incredibly easy to get going (on every platform just it just worked out of the box). The advantage of C++ is that you can use native GUIs on each platform, but if you're not already into C++ I'd say a cross platform project is a pretty ambitious first project.

Comment: +1 for RtMidi. Watch out though, if you want to open virtual midi ports on OS X the RtMidi implementation does not allow you to retain same-named virtual ports across runs.

Answer (score 2):

One *possibility* is .NET (C# or VB.Net), which runs on Windows (of course) and Mac (thanks to Mono).  The downside is that .NET does not have any native support for MIDI, so you'd have to tap into two different native APIs for MIDI.

Java is another possibility, since it has a number of MIDI-supporting libraries available.  Your UI is bound to look pretty terrible, though.

Comment: @liquidblueocean: I'm sure you have better uses for your time than posting useless comments like this.

Comment: We've successfully written a MIDI app on both Windows and Mac using Mono. Although we used a WinForms UI on Windows and a Cocoa  UI on the Mono app. They shared some code of course, but not 100%.

Comment: @IainMNorman: MIDI sample dump standard or just plain MIDI? Is this a publicly-available app I could check out?

Answer (score 1):

Python  has substantial support for MIDI and runs on Mac and Win.
pygame.midi
PyPortMidi
PythonMIDI
pyrtmidi

Answer (score 0):

For both mac and windows I would suggest Java.  Midi is just a protocol so any language can do it.  A good framework will speed things up a lot.  Java has frameworks to work with Midi and other multimedia sources.

Answer (score 0):

[PortMidi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PortMidi) is another popular cross-platform MIDI library.  [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) is a nice cross-platform Framework, GUI and utility library.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but nowdays you can use .NET. I mean official cross-platform .NET from Microsoft, not Mono. In this case I can recommend my library – [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi). Its core part (working with MIDI files, processing MIDI data and so on) is cross-platform for any OS supported by .NET.

As for working with MIDI devices, this API supports Windows and macOS (that's what you need). Full documentation of the library availabale here: https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi. There you can find full API reference and help articles. For example, overview article on [working with MIDI devices](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/devices/Overview.html).

The library is distributed via [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Melanchall.DryWetMidi/) and can be installed via NuGet on both Windows and macOS.